# Creating symlink setting up Laravel 5.6 on a remote server

Tags: laravel, symlink

I'm setting up a Laravel 5.6 site in a remote shared hosting server. 
I'm failing at creating the storage symlink. I'm executing a file with the following line (as Laravel documentation and other tutorials instruct):

```
symlink('/home/nataliag/laravel/storage/app/public', '/home/nataliag/public_html/storage');
```

this creates a symlink, but instead of getting my images with mydomain.com/img/..., i have to go mydomain.com/storage/img/....

what link the `php artisan storage:link` creates? because that works in local, and all my links are created following that structure

Comment: To get url `mydomain.com/img/` I think you need to configure in the `.htaccess` file. Symlink will create `mydomain.com/storage/img/`url for the files. You cannot use `/home/nataliag/public_html/` only. It does not link with storage folder

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: @RossWilson, Laravel version in the title (5.6), no ssh access

Comment: @Ahsan which htaccess config you mean? what link the `php artisan storage:link` creates? because that works in local, and all my links are created following that strcture

Comment: If you don't have ssh access are you able to run artisan commands e.g. `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: no, i have to create a php file `<?php symlink('route1', 'route2');` and run it